# How to read property of 'id' using express-session?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my mongoose schema for work:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var WorkSchema = mongoose.Schema({
Title:{
    type:String,
    required:true, 
    unique:true
},
   VideoURL:String,
   Image: { data: Buffer, contentType: String },
   Price:Number,
   Username:String,
   Company_id:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'Company'}]

});

var Work = module.exports = mongoose.model("Work", WorkSchema);
```

And this is the my work controller:

```
    let Work = require('../Models/Work');
    let Company = require('../Models/Company');
    let WorkController = {
     createWork:function(req, res){

       let   trial = new  Work();
       console.log( req.session.Username+ " session");
       trial.Username= req.session.Username;
       trial.VideoURl= req.body.VideoURl;
       trial.Price=req.body.Price;
       trial.Title= req.body.Title;
       User=req.session.Username;

Company.findOne( {Username:User},function(err, company){
            trial.Company_id=company._id;


            trial.save(function(err, Work){
            if(err){
               res.send(err.message);
               console.log(err);
           }


          });
       });
    }
 }


 module.exports = WorkController;
```

And this is my schema for Company:
    let Company = require('../Models/Company');

```
let CompanyController = {



login:function(req,res){
var Username = req.body.Username;
var  Password =req.body.Password;

 Company.findOne({Username:Username,Password:Password},function(err,Company)
    {
      if(!Company){

              return console.log('you are not athorized ');
 res.status(500).send(errorMsg);

                 ;}
            else{
                 res.json(Company);
                req.session.Username = Company.Username;
                console.log("username session: " + req.session.Username);

              }
        })
  }
,

      createCompany:function(req, res){
         let company = new  Company(req.body);

   company.save(function(err, company){
            if(err){
                res.send(err.message)
               console.log(err);
            }
             else{
  req.session.Username= req.body.Username;

                console.log(company);

            }
         })
    }
}

  module.exports = CompanyController;
```

When the the company user logs in and tries to create work, this error appears in the console "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null"

Comment: You're not describing the problem very specifically.  I can't see anywhere in this code looking for a property "id" so this could be in your server script. What line is logging that? Maybe add more information into your console.log(err) so you know which line is getting the error - you could also try console.trace(err)